# Assignment Branch Condition size for from_omniauth is too high

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I fixed assignment branch condition warnings for below code

```
      def self.from_omniauth(ominiauth_data)
        data = ominiauth_data.info
        if data['email'].present?
          user = User.where(email: data['email']).try(:last)
        else
          if ominiauth_data['provider'] == 'twitter'
            uname = ominiauth_data.info['nickname'].delete(' ')
          elsif ominiauth_data['provider'] == 'facebook'
            uname = ominiauth_data.info['name'].delete(' ')
          elsif ominiauth_data['provider'] == 'google_oauth2'
            uname = ominiauth_data.info['name'].delete(' ')
          end
          user = User.where(username: uname).try(:last)
        end
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def self.from_omniauth(ominiauth_data)
    if ominiauth_data.info['email'].present?
      user = User.where(email: data['email']).try(:last)
    else
      uname = case ominiauth_data['provider']
              when 'twitter' then ominiauth_data.info['nickname'].delete(' ')
              when 'facebook' then ominiauth_data.info['name'].delete(' ')
              when 'google_oauth2' then ominiauth_data.info['name'].delete(' ')
              end
      user = User.where(username: uname).try(:last)
    end
 end
```

or, even better:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(ominiauth_data)
    if ominiauth_data.info['email'].present?
      user = User.where(email: data['email']).try(:last)
    else
      uname = ominiauth_data.info[
                case ominiauth_data['provider']
                when 'twitter' then 'nickname'
                when 'facebook' then 'name'
                when 'google_oauth2' then 'name'
                end
              ].delete(' ')
      user = User.where(username: uname).try(:last)
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can see twitter also provides `name` [see hear](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash)

(and `nickname` already without spaces!!!)

So you can write your code in next way:

```
def self.from_omniauth(ominiauth_data)
    data = ominiauth_data.info
    if data['email'].present?
      user = User.where(email: data['email']).try(:last)
      # if you have uniq user than use
      # user = User.find_by(email: data['email'])
    else
      uname = data.info['nickname'].delete(' ')
      user = User.where(username: uname).try(:last)
      # if you have uniq user than use
      # user = User.find_by(username: uname)
    end
 end
```

**EDIT**

BTW
bad idea to change origin user's name, why?
For example:
Twitter doesn't provide email and you can identify user by name. But `Oleg Sobchuk` and `OlegSobchuk` may be two difference users.

Better way to save `privider` and `uid`. This two attributes UNIQ. And you can use them like major and other like helpers (e.g. email)